# Getting error while executing shell script in Cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, bash-scripting

I have done a script (bash) and kept the same in E:\Ping folder of my local Windows 7 m/c, and I am trying to run the same through Cygwin. I'm getting a `bash: sh : command not found` error. What is causing this error?

Steps I have followed:

```
cd /cygdrive/e/Ping

sh ping.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

`./script.sh` is the correct way of calling executable scripts.

Verify you actually have sh by running `/bin/sh` if not install it with cygwins integrated package manager.